# can neo4j be used with RailwayJS

Tags: orm, neo4j, railway.js

I'm having trouble using neo4j as my backing database to a RailwayJS starter project.  I updated the database.json file to point my local neo4j instance but it seems to just hang when I call any route with data access.

Here's what's in my database.json file

```
{ 
"development":
  { "driver":   "neo4j" , "url":     "http://localhost:7474/"}
, "test":
  { "driver":   "memory"
  }
}
```

Does RailwayJS support neo4j?  Is there something I need to configure it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about RailwayJS, but there is a driver for Node.js, see https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/

Would love to see some blog or so when you get it working!

Comment: thanks for the advice, will spend a bit more time trying to get jugglingdb working since that's what railway uses..